# use custom comparator for a specific set

Tags: python

I am storing a number of objects in a set. Is there a way to override the comparator function used just for that set? I know I can override `__eq__` and friends but I don't want to do so as I am also storing those objects in other sets.

Illustration:

```
# suppose Person class has name and address fields
p1 = Person("Alice", "addr1")
p2 = Person("Alice", "addr2")
s1 = set(p1, p2, [equality based on name only])  # this should contain only one of p1 or p2
s2 = set(p1, p2)  # this should contain p1 and p2
```

Comment: You can write a `set` subclass that behaves differently.

Comment: Do you care which of `p1` or `p2` is chosen? You can use `itertools.groupby` to  group the items by name, then take the first element of each group.

Comment: You could subclass `set` but that's not a great idea. Better to use a ***set comprehension***. The `itertools.groupby` suggestion is good.

Comment: Related: [Set comprehension and different comparable relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190339/set-comprehension-and-different-comparable-relations)

Comment: Can we assume your `Person` object has at most two attributes, hence the dict hack approach is acceptable? (IMO that's hacky and limiting)

Answer (score 0):

`set` doesn't provide a way to determine whether two objects are equivalent; it leaves that up to the class.

However, you can *group* the objects by an arbitrary predicate, then construct an appropriate sequence to pass to `set`.

Here's a solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def get_name(p):
    return p.name  # or however you get the name of a Person instance


s1 = set(next(v) for _, v in groupby(sorted([p1, p2], key=get_name), get_name))
```

After sorting by name, `groupby` will put all `Person`s with the same name in a single group. Iterating over the resulting sequence yields tuples like `("Alice", <sequence of Person...>)`. You can ignore the key, and just call `next` on the sequence to get *an* object with the name `Alice`.

Note that depending on how you do the grouping, "equal" elements can still end up in the different groups, and `set` will discard the duplicates as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a dictionary (which kind of uses a set under-the-hood):

```
# Just to simulate a class, not really necessary
import collections
Person = collections.namedtuple('Person', ('name', 'address'))

people = [Person("Alice", "addr1"), Person("Alice", "addr2"), Person("Bob", "addr1")]
s = set({person.name: person for person in people}.values())

print(s)
# Output: {Person(name='Bob', address='addr1'), Person(name='Alice', address='addr2')}
```